# Every quadratic number field is contained in a cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Why is every quadratic number field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is contained in a cyclotomic field $\mathbb Q(C_n)$, where $C_n$ is the primitive n-th root of unity?

Comment: Well, if you want the heavy hammer, it’s because the Galois group is abelian, and so by the Kronecker-Weber Theorem the extension is contained in a cyclotomic extension. But presumably, you don’t know this yet. So this leads to the request: *please provide context*! Tell us what you do know, or where this question came about, so that the answers can be cast at the appropriate level with the appropriate level of assumed background.

Comment: I wanted to ask which quadratic number fields are subfields of cyclotomic fields, and this quesitin answers that. I'm making this comment to be able to find this question later and also to link to [Wikipedia's article about the Kronacker-Weber theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem).

Answer (score 5):

Write $\zeta_n=\exp(2\pi i/n)$.

When $p\equiv1\pmod 4$ is prime, then $\sqrt p=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\zeta_p^{k^2}$
(quadratic Gauss sum).

When $p\equiv3\pmod 4$ is prime, then $i\sqrt p=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\zeta_p^{k^2}$
(quadratic Gauss sum).

$i=\zeta_4$.

$\sqrt 2=\zeta_8+\zeta_8^7$.

So all these square roots are in some cyclotomic field. But every $\sqrt d$
for $d\in\Bbb Z$ is a product of a bunch of these, so also must lie
in some cyclotomic field.

Comment: There’s surely a line that explains that the compositum of finitely many cyclotomic fields is contained in a cyclotomic field that ismissing there at the end...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! One last question: What would be the smallest cyclotomic field that contains the quadratic number field $\mathbb Q(i) $ ?

Comment: @StMan $\Bbb Q(i)=\Bbb Q(\zeta_4)$ **is** a cyclotomic field.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok, so $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{-3} ) $ and $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{5} ) $ are also cyclotomic fields?